# How to Record the call in webrtc Swift - iOS

Tags: webrtc, record, audio-recording, apprtc, call-recording

how to record the live audio conversation in webrtc using Swift and is it possible to record all calls conversation automatically and save them.

I can record only one side of the stream and i m not able to record the other stream who is calling.

Comment: I have same problem what you are facing...

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?